# JSON to describe HTML tags

Tags: html, json, parsing

I have a need to express HTML tags in a user friendly format, and then render them as actual HTML on a Web Page.

For example, imagine that a user would like this link to show up on the page:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

My average user is not familiar with HTML, so I was thinking about letting him/her use JSON instead. Something like this:

```
{Link:{Title:"Stack Overflow",URL:"http://stackoverflow.com"}}
```

I would then use a JSON parser to render the actual HTML on the page. The same method would apply to other HTML tags (images, buttons, etc.).

Has this already been done? Are there any conventions on how to express HTML tags in JSON?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of user knows JSON but not HTML?  How would you put bold text in a link?

Comment: Agreed, probably not the best idea. Especially because JSON can become syntactically complex with large nested structures etc.

Comment: Why not use some already-existing lightweight markup language like Markdown, or bbcode, or txt2tags?

Comment: @SLaks: agree, but my point was that JSON would be more human friendly, making it easier to learn. @ZeSimon: my objective is not to build a whole page, just to allow users to insert common elements like links, images and buttons. @zerocrates: well, maybe it's just what I was looking for, just I never heard about those before. Would you mind posting an answer with more details? User friendly is my main requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that there is a category of languages called "lightweight markup languages" that just do that. Thanks @zerocrates for the pointers. I found more details here (including for each the implementation language or platform):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language

Also, good to know that ExtJS has a syntax for that (thanks @Pumbb80). It just won't work in my case because I am targeting end users.

Answer (score 1):

[ExtJS's DOMHelper class](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.DomHelper) provides a syntax like this:

```
{
    id: 'my-ul',
    tag: 'ul',
    cls: 'my-list',
    children: [
        {tag: 'li', id: 'item0', html: 'List Item 0'},
        {tag: 'li', id: 'item1', html: 'List Item 1'},
        {tag: 'li', id: 'item2', html: 'List Item 2'}
    ]
}
```